# Add Rich Text to List View without changing ribbon context?

Tags: 2010, list-view, ribbon, cewp

I have a few Lists and Libraries in my Sharepoint 2010 farm that I have added small instructions to.

For example:
[image: Calendar View with text]

This particular image is a calendar list view page of which I used the site actions menu to edit and add a CEWP. Of course, now the ribbon no longer by default display's the calendar list tab group. I have to actually click the list and THEN, I can see the calander controls.

 **How can I make the ribbon display the current list's context options without clicking it?**

If code is needed, JS/xslt is prefered.